# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Maven project, while trying to load listener from web.xml

Tags: maven, listener, web.xml, classnotfoundexception

I have converted existing web project into Maven, technologies used are : Struts 2, Hibernate. A listener extends  `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`, which has a entry in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.tcs.weserv.util.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Maven project is built successfully, but when I try to start the server, it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.util.Listener
```

All dependencies are defined properly in `pom.xml`, listener is available at given location, still it throws `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Post a stacktrace()

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tcs.weserv.util.Listener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)

Comment: Describe the steps you followed to "convert" your project. Please add the `<build>...</build` fragment of your pom.xml file to your question

Comment: I have created a new maven web project, and then paste all java src to main/resources including struts.xml and hibernate.xml file. copied all webContent into webApp folder.  Here is the build in pom.xml              <build>
    <finalName>Workbench</finalName>
  </build>

Comment: To debug, I have created a demo project in maven , which will call the same listener(which is used to create hibernate session), at first time, it was giving the same ClassNotFoundException, but when I cleaned the project , It worked fine. same is not applicable in my actual project.

Comment: I am facing following error while starting the server : SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class, followed by ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your valuable comments. It helped to debug the problem. The actual problem is, Maven Project structure was wrong. When I created a Maven project by selecting archtype as webapp, the project structure contains only `src/main/resources`.

Since I am new to Maven, I thought this is actual project structure, and I copied all resources as well as java files into this folder. As a result, It was able to build the project without any error, but while deploying it on server, It is showing `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: You can formally approve your answer to make evident that it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is uknown listener. Cannot find any jar containing that listener. If you know how to create jar using some zip utility or jar executable then you can copy the class `com.tcs.weserv.util.Listener.class` to the jar file preserving the folder structure which is important to find the corresponding class.

Comment: this listener is defined in my project itself. n before converting the project to maven , it was working fine.

Comment: If it is in the project, why it cant find it , n says ClassNotFoundExceprtion.

Comment: the file should be on classpath and the server should be able to load it

Comment: see.. its a simple class which implements ServletContextListener. n It is in the project only. If i build the project , it should automatically in the war file. so.. while starting server, it is available on the specified path. I could not understand what do u mean by "file should be on classpath" ?

Comment: this is the thing that you don't understand. The class couldn't be loaded if it's not available. Verify your package or whatever you use to deploy your application to have consistent packaging that requires to build and start the web application.

Comment: Hi @Roman, I have cross checked war file, and it contains the class.   30217 Thu May 25 18:09:48 IST 2017 WEBINF/classes/com/tcs/weserv/util/Listener.java

Comment: In the exception message you say that it is `package.util.Listener`

Comment: last time, i haven't explained it in details, here package mean to com/tcs/weserv. The actual location of the listener is com.tcs.weserv.util

Comment: I didn't see where you explained it in details? You shouldn't substitute real values with imaginable. Nobody can understand this. I recommend you to check the `lib` folder to have the same jars as in working project. Maven is downloading jars and replaces them in the `lib` folder. You might have inconsistent project dependencies that failed on the server loading your class. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413/573032